# How to configure mocha when external dependencies are involved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

My folder structure is

```
-assets

    - apps
        - login
            -adminLogin.js
    - data
        - trackerDb.js
-specs

    - apps
        -login
            -adminLogin_spec.js
```

`specRunner.js`

I have `specRunner.js` file which i have added as test initialization in `package.json` in root like

"test": "node assets/spec_Runner.js"
This specrunner includes the all the test that needs to be run.

The first line of `adminLogin.js` is
 `define("trackerDb"),function(tracker){ //complete code}` 
Now when i am writing test case for this source file 
and running it, throws error like `"cannot find trackerDb.js"`

So my question is do i need to pass every js file with relative path .. if so then what about external module like jquery,
underscore etc..

Do we have any other way by which we can directly configured mocha so that it can find every path.